# Difference Between Dirac delta and unit impulse function

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

The definition of Dirac delta function states that it gives a value of $\infty$ at t=0 and 0 elsewhere.

But, the definition of unit impulse function states that it gives a value of 1 at t=0 and 0 elsewhere.

Many textbooks state that Dirac delta and unit impulse are the same function.

So What is the difference between Dirac delta and unit impulse function?

Comment: The “definition” of a Dirac delta says _nothing_ of the kind of things you say it does. If you find a textbook or paper that gives what you state above as the definition of a Dirac delta, throw the book away. If your professor wrote it on the blackboard, find a different professor or course.

Answer (score 4):

"Unit impulse" is a generic term that, depending on context, refers to one of the following distributions:

- [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), denoted $\delta(t)$, for a continuous domain
- [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_function), sometimes denoted $\delta[k]$, for a discrete domain

They are both referred to as "unit impulse", because they both represent the response of a system to a short "impulsive" input, and have 
 similar properties that translate between continuous and discrete domains, such as the sifting property:
$$
f(t_0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t - t_0) f(t) dt
$$
for Dirac delta and
$$
f[k_0] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \delta[k - k_0] f_k
$$
for the Kronecker delta.

Answer (score 3):

The Dirac delta $\delta(x)$ is a continuous argument (generalized) function where $x$ is a continuous variable and can be time, space, frequency etc. Unfortunately, a simple definition like

$$\delta(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\infty ~~~&,~~~ x=0 \\
0 ~~~&,~~~ x \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

does or can not properly describe its behaviour. You need to define its properties under the integral sign, and that requires advanced mathematical stuff for a formal verification. But  a simplified Riemann definition of $\delta(x)$ is given as:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x-a) dx = f(a)$$ for a sufficiently smooth test function $f(x)$. All properties of $\delta(x)$ follows from this Riemann (seeming) integral operation.

On the other hand, the discrete counterpart, the unit-impulse or the Kronecker delta is a sequence of integer index $m$ with very well defined behaviour as:

$$\delta[m] = \begin{cases}
1 ~~~&,~~~ m=0 \\
0 ~~~&,~~~ m \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
These two functions serve the same purpose for discrete and continuous systems, hence share the same name *impulse*. Yet they are two different, distinct entities; the Dirac impulse is a very problematic concept, whereas the discrete  impulse is a mere simplicity.

Comment: excuse me, what does "does not properly describe it's behaviour" mean?

Comment: Too see why that definition cannot describe Dirac impulse fully, you should better read a chapter of a signal processing book. In summary, Dirac impulse is defined with respect to its effects under integral sign: for a smooth (continuous) test function (at t=0) of $\phi(t)$ the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) \delta(t) dt = \phi(0)$$, and properties of $\delta(x)$ follow from this defintion. For example $x(t)\delta(t-a) = x(a)\delta(t-a)$ or $x(t) \star \delta(t-d) = x(t-d)$ or $\delta(at) = \frac{1}{|a|} \delta(t)$...

Comment: that was helpful thank you sir,could you tell me the name of that particular chapter . Actually i'm new to dsp.

Comment: Mostly those chapters that introduce various **signals** into the scene. Sometimes thos chapters taht intoruduce the impulse response. For example  Chapter 2 of Signals & Systems, Oppenheim is an example. Similar chapters from Lathi, Haykin would also suffice.

Comment: Just bouncing on "You need the integral of it". My knowledge of the integral world is shallow. Do you know which integral is sufficient for signals: Stieltjes?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Honestly, the question was not about the nature of the demon $\delta(x)$ but rather its distinction from the crystal clear $\delta[n]$. So I provided the least answer. May be a separate threat (if not already) would be better to discuss that. Afaik, the integral I used in the **comment** imitates Riemann sense. So the unknown *thing* $\delta(x)$ is such a function that  $$\int_{a^-}^{a^+} f(x)\delta(x-a)dx = f(a)$$ So this **seems** like a Riemann integral, but it may not formally be... Lebesgue integration and Measure Theory should be invoked for a formal discussion though.

Comment: Do not worry, I upvoted your answer. A separate question and thread is probably wiser. I suppose Lebesque is too much, looking for something between him and Riemann

Comment: @LaurentDuval There is a book from *Lighthill* which is about *...distributions...*; (*introduction to Fourier Analysis and Generalised Functions - 1959*) afaik it's one of the most referenced books while defering the formal discussion of $\delta(x)$, so may be you can have a look at it for an easy introduction to formal treatment of distributions...

Comment: I appreciate the Lighthill mention. I have skimmed several other distribution sources. I was wondering about: what just sufficient for most DSP needs?

Comment: @LaurentDuval From a DSP *engineering* perspective, I've never seen a serious discussion of its true mathematical nature, or seen an algorithm that depends on different interpretations of dirac delta. It's just used the way it's defined in this post... If you are into just the sufficieny, then you may read Oppenheim's signals & systems chapter 2. That's just sufficient upto PhD in DSP level...(unless you would be doing your work on *distributions* themselves of course :-) )

Comment: Recently, H. G. Feichtinger proposed [Distribution Theory by Riemann Integrals
](Distribution Theory by Riemann Integrals): It is the purpose of this article to outline a course that can be given to engineers looking for an understandable mathematical description of the foundations of distribution theory and the necessary functional analytic methods.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Very nice effort. A good read for spare time enthusiasm. Ineed, imho mathematical topology, set theory and measure theory are the fundamental obstackles before distributions...

Answer (score 1):

In

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions

gives as a *loose definitiniton*

$$
\delta(x)=\begin{cases} +\infty & x=0 \\
                         0  & x\ne0 \end{cases}
$$
so perhaps biting your head off is a bit severe.  I'm not about to throw Wikipedia away.

The rest of the article along with
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta
answers most of your question

Comment: that *loose definitiniton* is crappy.  someone should fix that in Wikipedia.

Comment: just calling it the way i see it

Comment: yer fine, Stan.  i also checked the Wikipedia page and it says that.  but, while i am **not** the Dirac distribution Nazi (i am generally fine treating it as a function that is a limit of functions **all** having an area of 1) that definition from Wikipedia **is crappy** and should be fixed.  e.g. suppose we  define it like this:

$$ f_a(x) \triangleq \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{a^2} \qquad & \text{for } x=0 \\
0 &\text{for } x\ne 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

then define

$$ \delta(x) \triangleq \lim_{a\to 0} f_a(x) $$

what's the integral of $\delta(x)$ in the limit?

Comment: The loose definition is confusing,how can we replace infinity(at x=0) with the integral of the function I.e 1 (at x=0) ?

Comment: read the article

Comment: but the the integral of $f_a(\cdot)$ is zero for any non-zero $a$, no matter how close $a$ gets to zero.  so the limit of that integral is zero.  that makes that *loose definition* insufficient.

Comment: if you have a better way to express a point mass you should use it. it’s the physical interpretation that the loose definition caters to. paraphrasing Heaviside, rigor be damned.

Comment: look up the radius of an electron on the web. The sites I looked at say $<10^{-18}$ m and that’s an upper bound. Lower bounds seem hard to find. I think the loose definition appeals to ones intuition rather well but I find myself advocating here for something I loosely hold. If you think the loose definition stinks from a mathematical perspective, that is fine. Physics and Math intersect but don’t always harmonize

Answer (score 0):

Dirac Delta function and unit impulse function are the same. But many texts define that $\delta(t) = \left \lbrace
\begin{array}{lr}
\infty,  \hspace{0.5cm} t=0 \\
0, \hspace{0.5cm} else \
\end{array} \right .
 $
But I am of the opinion that this definition is not perfect. Because $\infty$ is something that is not defined. How can one insert something that is not defined as a quintessential part of a definition? So I think what Simon Haykins defined it, is perfect:

$\delta(t) = 
0 \hspace{0.5cm} for \hspace{0.5cm} t \neq 0 
 $
and $\int_ \limits{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta (t)dt = 1$

Answer (score -1):

Dirac Delta function(better distribution) and unit impulse are exactly same but we interpret the definition in a different way.

When we refer to this function as Dirac Delta we consider the magnitude of the distribution at every point. Hence this gives value infinite at t=0 and zero other wise.

When we refer to signal as unit impulse the values we refer are the areas of integration around that particular point with limits t- to t+. This gives value 1 to the unit impulse representation of the function.

To clarify further they are in CT domain ie continues time domain but there DT version is kroneker delta, this is defined on only integral values of n, whereas you see the unit impulse or Dirac Delta function as you may know is defined for all real values of t.

Source:Signals and Systems by  Oppenheim (Professor at MIT)